# set default device (png) with default height and width

Tags: r, graphics

I'm setting the default device to PNG `options(device="png")`.

For one plot, I can make a PNG in R with particular dimensions using `png(...)`:

```
v <- 1:10
png("squared.png", width = 960, height = 480)
plot(v, v**2)
dev.off()
```

But I want to set the default height/width (just like I'm setting the default device) so that all plots come out with my desired height and width.

Comment: can you just make a wrapper and use that ? `png2 <- function(...) png(width = 960, height = 480, ...)`

Comment: I'm setting up an environment where I want things to be as nice as possible for my users if they just say `plot(...)` (or `ggplot(...) + ....`). They'll sometimes explicitly save things instead of relying on the default device, and then they'll specify dimensions they want (and a helper function like yours might be good)... but I'm hoping to get the defaults as good as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, this is what I'm looking for:

`options(device = function() png(width = 960))`

The `device` argument should be

> a character string giving the name of a function, or the function object itself, which when called creates a new graphics device of the default type for that session...

Using a function instead of the string `"png"` gives me the flexibility I need.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you re-define png? If you type png into the console, R will display the function code. You can copy and paste it into an R script, changing its defaults. Then, the autocomplete of the function arguments will still work.

Comment: The thing that `options(device="png")` achieves is that you don't explicitly have to call `png` for PNGs to get created. So after that option is set, just saying `plot(v, v**2)` creates a PNG. I'm looking for something that sticks with not having to explicitly call `png`.