# Some legend elements disappear when points plotted with alpha<1 with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This plot is generated with alpha = 0.5 for the points. In the legend most of the point shapes are not displayed on-screen. The fix suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71953134/ggplot-line-legend-disappears-with-alpha-1) doesn't work. Full code for this display:

```
qq <- data.table(LSGrp = factor(1:4), Incent=1:4, Size=1:4, LnNum = 1:4, Actual=4:1, Age=10:13)
ggplot(data=qq,
                aes(x=Incent, y=Actual, fill=Age, shape=LSGrp, size=LnNum) ) +
        geom_point(col='black', alpha=0.5) + 
        scale_fill_distiller(type='seq', palette='Spectral', guide='colorbar') +
        scale_shape_manual(values=c(21:24)) + 
        guides(size=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=21, title='Ln Num', alpha=1)),
                shape=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=4), title='Size', alpha=1)) + 
        ylab("Observed") + xlab("Incentive")
```

Removing the "alpha=0.5" in the geom_point specification "fixes" the issue, but in the actual use (not this toy instance) is unsuitable because of overplotting. This seems like a bug? Directly outputting the plot to a file (e.g., with png()) produces the desired result, but the screen plot driver seems to have a problem.
[image: on-screen graph]

ETA: I added data & simplified to make the problem reproduceable. The given code shows the problem with slightly different displayed data but the same legend issue. Further, while I originally saw the problem in "native" R (R.exe) run within emacs, the same problem is visible in RStudio. The R version is 4.1.2, the ggplot2 version is 3.4.2.

Comment: the thread you linked to provided a runnable example of the problem; you did not, so you are making it much harder to help you than otherwise. If there's a genuine bug and this is not a user error then ggplot2 has a github page with an issue tracker for you to log to.

Comment: *"Directly outputting the plot to a file (e.g., with png()) produces the desired result, but the screen plot driver seems to have a problem."* If the PNG file appears correctly, then yes, it would seem this is a problem with the graphics device, not really anything to do with ggplot. What is your graphics device? Are you using RStudio, VS Code, the RGui, or something else?

Comment: @GregorThomas This is on Windows, running Rterm inside emacs. Not RStudio.

Comment: If you're using RStudio, if you go to Tools > Global Options > General > Graphics, what is selected as the Graphics Device backend? If it's not AGG, I'd suggest installing the `ragg` package, selecting the AGG backend graphics device, and seeing if that fixes the problem. If not, please share enough sample data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ah, I'm not at all familiar with that set-up. I'd still suggest installing the `ragg` package and attempting to make your default graphics device use AGG as the backend, perhaps something like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29175924/903061) but with an `agg_*` function instead of `png()`.

Comment: And I'd recommend editing your question to include all this information up top - your question reads as if `ggplot` is the problem, until the last sentence reveals that `ggplot` is incidental. Lead with *"When I save my plot as a PNG it looks great, but the graphic displayed by Rterm (on Windows, using emacs) doesn't show all the points in the legend."* That's the heart of the problem.

Comment: @GregorThomas, I believe it _is_ a ggplot problem. A minor change to the call _within ggplot_ exhibits the issue. Also the same problem can be produced in RStudio.

Comment: In my RStudio with the AGG graphics device backend selected, when I run your code it looks just fine. And even on your system, when you use `png()` the problem is not there. Unless you've changed the setting, RStudio is probably using the same graphics device backend as your Rterm. So it seems like a graphics device problem.

Comment: @GregorThomas I think you're correct that it's a display graphics driver problem. It seems like initializing the window with a different size (rather than resizing it manually) makes the problem disappear. Not sure how to get ragg to work as a display driver - while it's an option in RStudio, it doesn't seem to offer a substitute for the windows driver in R.exe. Anyway, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: It should be very settable... somewhere. [See here for another similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10777008/903061). I'm on a Mac using RStudio, so I can't experiment to see what works, but there should be a way to do it. You could ask another question directly about that: "How do I set AGG as the default graphics backend for Rterm on Windows?"